# Dynamic Date Picker Android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I need to develop an application that requires the user to select multiple dates in Calendar

```
Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(DatePicker.this,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                EditText edt_Bdate=(EditText)findViewById(id);
                edt_Bdate.setText(year+"-"+(monthOfYear+1)+"-"+dayOfMonth);


            }
        },cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        return datePicker;
    }
}
```

but this code is deprecated